# Как узнать, что ячейка является объединенной? python

Tags: python, excel, gspread

Как узнать, что ячейка является объединенной? Я использую gspread для того чтобы получить данные к файлу и дальше работаю с ячейками, но как мне узнать есть ли эта клетка объединена?

ps. help :_

Comment: Может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901345/get-combined-merged-cells-value. И утилита https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.10.0/api/utils.html#gspread.utils.combined_merge_values